# Javascript checking if function exists using a closure and arguments.callee

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures

I using a nice trick to check if an async loaded javascript file with a function `myFunction` exists. The trick is a `closure` using `arguments.callee`:

```
(function() {
  if(typeof myFunction === "undefined") {
    console.log("not loaded");
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
  } else {
    console.log("loaded");
  }
})();
```

Is this the best way of doing this though? Is there any issue with browser compatibility using `arguments.callee`?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the event thrown when the file is loaded ? What you try to achieve isn't clear.

Comment: Can you give an example, not sure what you mean event thrown?

Comment: The only correct way to do this isn't to regularly check but to execute your code when the file is loaded. How do you load this file ?

Comment: seriously, @dystroy is right. `scriptNode.onload` is there for you.

Comment: Your questions seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish via this code?

Comment: I don't have the ability to edit the code in the file being loaded async.

Comment: @Justin You don't have to edit the loaded code. The loading one can receive an event on load.

Comment: @dystroy would you mind giving an example? Thanks much.

Comment: @Justin It entirely depends on the way you asynchronously load this js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should not poll for the presence of a function.  If possible, you should monitor for an event that is triggered when the script is loaded.  See [this article](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/109) for how to monitor for the loading of dynamically loaded scripts and you can easily find other examples via Google.

If the script is loaded via a `<script>` tag and it's not async or defer then it will be loaded sychronously so that any code after will be safe to access that script.

---

While it would be better to use the actual event that is triggered when the script is loaded (and that's really what you should figure out how to do), you can wean your technique from `arguments.callee` like this:

```
(function() {
  function check() {
    if(typeof myFunction === "undefined") {
      console.log("not loaded");
      setTimeout(check, 100);
    } else {
      console.log("loaded");
    }
  }
  check();
})();
```

A good reason to stop using `arguments.callee` is that it is not present in ECMA5 strict mode.

---

If you care to provide some context for how the script with this function in it is being loaded, then we might be able to provide you some options for better ways to know when it's loaded because polling for it is certainly not the best way.

Comment: As an experienced user, you shouldn't give this answer. You know the only reasonable solution is to avoid this trick and to call the function when the file is loaded.

Comment: @dystroy - My answer says that the best way to do this is to hook into an event when the script is loaded, but the OP doesn't provide any context for how to do that so I told them that and then answered their specific question.  If you think there's enough information for a better answer, why don't you provide one?  I added a few more disclaimers about how this is certainly not the best way to do it.

Comment: Here is the code that loads the file async. I could modify it, but would prefer not too, since then I break changes when the author updates. http://pastie.org/6034236

Answer (score 0):

arguments.callee() is not allowed in strict mode and seems to be deprecated. According to the Mozilla Developer Network it also prevents a large number of possible optimizations.

An alternative approach would be to give your function expression a name and use that one in setTimeout. The name would only only be visible from within the function.

```
(function pollingFunction() {
  if(typeof myFunction === "undefined") {
    console.log("not loaded");
    setTimeout(pollingFunction, 100);
  } else {
    console.log("loaded");
  }
})();
```